# Couldn't create Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I couldn't create my Laravel project, it seemed to be something wrong when I tried to use Angular a few days ago with my PHP Storm. Is there any workaround for the situation I'm in

[image]

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work well, but I realized my Composer could not update even though I could still check its version.

Comment: it says the ext-dom extension is missing. You might have removed it (if it was there before) or updated to a new version of PHP without installing all the same extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Required php extensions are missing from your system.

Run the following command to install required php extensions for laravel. ( here im writing apt-get as I'm using ubuntu u have to change this according to your linux distro )

```
sudo apt-get install php-common php-mbstring php-xml php-zip php-curl
```

see other php extensions for ubuntu from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/cosmic/php-defaults), just install as per required.

Comment: `apt-get` requires an Ubuntu or Debian based OS (there's probably other Linux distros which have it). If using windows then enabling the extension requires editing php.ini for example and other Linux distros as well as Mac OS have other instructions

Comment: according to his screenshot, he is using ubuntu. thats why i placed apt-get. But you are right. i should add this in my answer.

Comment: I have tried and it works well, thank you for the help

Comment: @NgôThànhTân if any answer solves your query mark it as answer, it will help other user to find out the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

change group permission

```
sudo chown -R ngothanhtan /home/ngothanhtan/.composer/cache/files/
```

Comment: the require extension you can solve this issue by sudo apt-get install php-xml